# iOS app background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I was trying to add an image (640X1136PX) as background for a project with following code:

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
background.position =  CGPointMake(self.size.width * .5, self.size.height * .5);
background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
background.blendMode = SKBlendModeReplace;
[self addChild:background];
```

With the above code the background image is shown on left bottom showing hardly 10% of the image, if I comment the the following

```
 background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
```

Then it shows the image centered but the 30% of the area is not covered.
Please help me on this, I am very new to SpriteKit.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the image size. Does it fit the screen size?

Comment: @Astoria yes, image size is 640 X 1136 Px

Comment: The best solution is define the size of the scene `self.size = view.bounds.size`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach in your Scene-class. Try to leave `anchorPoint`-properties with default values.

```
- (void)constructBackground
{
  self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
  self.background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame);
  self.background.size = self.frame.size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me, i got fixed the issue, i am using xcode 6.0.1 and simulator is running iOS8 so we need to follow image conventions as per iOS8, when i resize the image to high resolution 1242 X 2208 px the issue was solved

@Astoria thanks for the clue.